# Handling Facebook API Permission skip / revoked per OAuth 2.0 RFC

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

Assume my application wishes to request permissions A and B on behalf of a user from a third party.

Per the OAuth 2.0 RFC, the third party need not grant those permissions. However, if the permissions returned are not equivalent to what my application requested for, the scopes that were granted would be returned in the third party response.

From reading the Facebook Documentation and examining responses back from Facebook when I simulate the skip / deny flow, it appears that granted scopes are not returned and that my application would need to make a follow up api call to see what permissions were granted.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: yes, you do.

Longer answer:
Make an API call to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE`  - in the PHP or JS SDK you can simplify this as just `/me/permissions` as the SDK will wrap the server and access token for you.

This shows all scopes currently granted to your application by that user, example output is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1, 
      "manage_friendlists": 1, 
      "status_update": 1, 
      "photo_upload": 1, 
      "video_upload": 1, 
      "create_event": 1, 
      "create_note": 1, 
      "share_item": 1, 
      "publish_stream": 1, 
      "publish_actions": 1, 
      "user_about_me": 1, 
      "friends_activities": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Because users can retroactively remove previously-granted permissions, you'll need to do this from time to time anyway, because even if you had a callback with the scopes granted in a particular permissions request, the user could revoke some/all of them almost immediately afterwards.

Comment: Thanks... was hoping that it would conform to the RFC though and I was just missing something =)